# creating new options for magento attributes

Tags: attributes, custom-options

I'm having problems trying to create a new option "Manage Options" when creating an attribute, do not know how to save the data correctly in the database, I'm overwriting "Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options" with my module to create custom fields, I want he save these fields when I save the attribute.

My Module:

config.xml

```
<config>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                     <catalog_product_attribute_edit_tabs>Ceicom_Swatches_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs</catalog_product_attribute_edit_tabs>
                     <catalog_product_attribute_edit_tab_options>Ceicom_Swatches_Block_Adminhtml_Options</catalog_product_attribute_edit_tab_options>
                 </rewrite>
             </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
</config>
```

Ceicom/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Options.php

```
class Ceicom_Swatches_Block_Adminhtml_Options extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Edit_Tab_Options
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('ceicom/attribute/options.phtml');
    }
}
```

in the phtml file I put in the custom fields

[image]

any idea how I can save the values ​​of these fields in the bank correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you need to add new columns to `eav_attribute_option` table.

For example **field_1**, **field_2**.

To make your additional fields save rewrite

`Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute::_saveOption()`

Find code:

```
$sortOrder = !empty($option['order'][$optionId]) ? $option['order'][$optionId] : 0;
if (!$intOptionId) {
    $data = array(
        'attribute_id'  => $object->getId(),
        'sort_order'    => $sortOrder
    );
    $adapter->insert($optionTable, $data);
    $intOptionId = $adapter->lastInsertId($optionTable);
} else {
    $data  = array('sort_order'    => $sortOrder);
    $where = array('option_id =?' => $intOptionId);
    $adapter->update($optionTable, $data, $where);
}
```

And change it to

```
$sortOrder = !empty($option['order'][$optionId]) ? $option['order'][$optionId] : 0;
$field1 = !empty($option['field1'][$optionId]) ? $option['field1'][$optionId] : '';
$field2 = !empty($option['field2'][$optionId]) ? $option['field2'][$optionId] : '';
$data = array(
    'sort_order'    => $sortOrder,
    'field1'        => $field1,
    'field2'        => $field2
);
if (!$intOptionId) {
    $data['attribute_id'] = $object->getId();
    $adapter->insert($optionTable, $data);
    $intOptionId = $adapter->lastInsertId($optionTable);
} else {
    $where = array('option_id =?' => $intOptionId);
    $adapter->update($optionTable, $data, $where);
}
```

The only thing that left is to display saved values in edit form.

Comment: I tried to rewrite using [this tip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262193/magento-how-to-overwrite-eav-resource-classes), but was unable to.
can tell me how to do use this code in module not modify the core

Comment: Please take a look on [this answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13822/wrap-sub-menu-items-in-div/13852#13852) it explains stap by stap how to create rewrite extension.

Comment: THX, but I need to overwrite the php file that contains saveoption() function